# Javascript - Inheritance and calling parent methods from child

Tags: javascript, methods, call, prototype, parent

i'm fighting around with oop in javascript for a few days now but i don't find a solution.

I've created 3 objects, a super class, a child class and an inheritance_manager which should do all the "prototype"-magic on my child classes.

The inheritance manager:

```
Inheritance_Manager = {};
Inheritance_Manager.extend = function(subClass, baseClass) {
    function inheritance() {
    }
    inheritance.prototype = baseClass.prototype;
    subClass.prototype = new inheritance();
    subClass.prototype.constructor = subClass;
    subClass.baseConstructor = baseClass;
    subClass.superClass = baseClass.prototype;
};
```

The super (parent) class:

```
SDSection = function(sectionId, resourceId) {

    this.self = this;
    this.sectionId = sectionId;
    this.resourceId = resourceId;

    ...
};

SDSection.prototype.doSetups = function() {
        ...
};
```

The child class:

```
TypedSectionHandler = function(sectionId, resourceId) {
    SDSection.call(this, sectionId, resourceId);
        ...
};

Inheritance_Manager.extend(TypedSectionHandler, SDSection);

TypedSectionHandler.prototype.doSetups = function() {
        ...
    SDSection.doSetups.call(this);
        ...
};
```

What i want to do is simple in other programming languages like php or java. I want to call the overwritten "doSetups"-method in the parent class "SDSection" from the method "doSetups" in child classes of type "TypedSectionHandler".

I'm struggling around with this problem for round about 1 week now and i tried different solutions, from basic to more complex, but nothing seems to work.

Everytime the script is executed for e.g. in chrome or firefox i will get the error "cannot call method call on undefined" or more simpler, "SDSection.doSetups" is not defined.

At least i picked up the above approach from [here](http://www.cyberminds.co.uk/blog/articles/how-to-implement-javascript-inheritance.aspx) and adapted it to my needs but it does not work anyway and the browser are quitting with the same error. Slowly i'm getting seriously nuts. :)

Does somebody know what i'm doing wrong and how a working solution will look like?

Thanks

Udo

Comment: `this.self = this;` makes absolutely no sense.

Answer (score 4):

You need to call the `doSetups` function that is part of the parent class's `prototype`.

```
TypedSectionHandler.prototype.doSetups = function() {
        ...
    SDSection.prototype.doSetups.call(this);
        ...
};
```

If you want to look at different techniques for inheritance (particularly, one which does not require the caller to know the parent type), you may want to check out CoffeeScript's `__extends` function, and how it performs inheritance.

Answer (score 3):

Use voithos' solution if you are doing pure javascript.  I like to use John Resig's [simple inheritance snippet](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/) in my current projects.  It's only 521 bytes after [minification](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home), with no dependencies, and in your case it would work like this:

```
SDSection = Class.extend({
    init: function(sectionId, resourceId) {

        this.sectionId = sectionId;
        this.resourceId = resourceId;

        ...
    },
    doSetups: function(){
        ...
    }
});

TypedSectionHandler = SDSection.extend({
    doSetups: function(){
        ...
        this._super();
        ...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it by yourself, you can go the way like **voithos** said - writing it on your own helps you understand js OOP for sure.

If you want to have **more comfort** (= not having to use `apply` and `call` and - if you're developing in Visual Studio 2012 - **base-methods/-constructor intellisense support**) I would like you to check out a framework I wrote: **[jsframework](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsframework/)**

With it you can write your sample really easy:

```
SDSection = new Class(Object, function(base, baseConstructor)
{
    // member fields for prototype
    this.self = null;
    this.sectionId = -1;
    this.resourceId = -1;

    // constructor
    this.init = function(sectionId, resourceId)
    {
        this.self = this;
        this.sectionId = sectionId;
        this.resourceId = resourceId;
    };

    // member functions
    this.doSetups = function() 
    {
        console.log("SDSection doSetups: " + this.sectionId + "/" + this.resourceId);
    };
});

TypedSectionHandler = new Class(SDSection, function(base, baseConstructor)
{
    this.anotherId = -2;

    // constructor
    this.init = function(sectionId, resourceId, anotherId) 
    {
        baseConstructor(sectionId, resourceId);

        this.anotherId = anotherId;
    };

    // member functions
    this.doSetups = function() 
    {
        // call base function
        base(this).doSetups();
        console.log("TypedSectionHandler doSetups: " + this.anotherId);
    };
});

var t = new TypedSectionHandler(1, 2, 3);
t.doSetups();
console.log(t instanceof TypedSectionHandler);
console.log(t instanceof SDSection);
```

Here's a working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QYXSr/1/

Output:

```
SDSection doSetups: 1/2
TypedSectionHandler doSetups: 3
true
true
```

### DISCLAIMER:

As I said, I'm the developer of this framework ;)